# PHP: Embedding a form inside Abraham's TwitterOAuth's callback template

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have managed to implement Twitter OAuth using Abraham's `twitteroauth`. After the user grants required permissions to my OAuth client, he/she is redirected back to `callback.php`. On my `callback.php` template, I have a basic HTML form, whose `method = "POST"`.

callback.php

```
<pre>
<?php
/*
 *Template Name: Callback 
*/

?>  
<?php

    session_start();
    require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
    use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

    define('CONSUMER_KEY', "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    define('CONSUMER_SECRET', "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', "http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/callback/");

    $request_token = [];
    $request_token['oauth_token'] = $_SESSION['oauth_token'];
    $request_token['oauth_token_secret'] = $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'];

    if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) && $request_token['oauth_token'] !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token'])
    {
        echo "Opps! Something went wrong!";
    }

    else
    {
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $request_token['oauth_token'], $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);
        $access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']));

        //print_r($access_token);

        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;

        $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];

        //print_r($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);


    }


?>

<script>

function printSomething()
{
    document.write("This works");
}

</script>


<form method = "post">

    <input type = "submit" onclick="printSomething()">

</form>
```

On clicking the `Submit` button, the message inside my `<script>` tags ie `This works` is printed, however, within seconds, the following Exception is raised:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException' with message 'This feature is temporarily unavailable' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/tuto/twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/tuto/callback.php(30): Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth->oauth('oauth/access_to...', Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/template-loader.php(74): include('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php(16): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/index.php(17): require('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/tuto/twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php on line 137
```

Even though at first glance it may seem to be a library issue, I don't think that's the case. I have tried sending various GET and POST requests to Twitter API using the access tokens, and everything seems to be working. However, each time I embed a form which sends a `POST` request on submission, the above mentioned Exception is raised.

What seems to be wrong here?